# How can I send to multiple wallets from a single PDA in a single transaction?

Tags: rust, pda, transaction

Very new at rust and Solana development, hoping to get some advice.

I am creating some blockchain functionality for a betting system. Players will bet on the outcome of a certain event by sending the details of their bet to my Solana program and their bet in SOL to a "fund account" PDA. When the outcome is determined, I determine who the winners are and collect their public keys and how much SOL should be sent to them. The program will use the PDA to send the SOL transactions. I am hoping this can be done in a single transaction to save on transaction fees.

I've created some simple scripts to test this functionality.

This is my rust program:

```
use borsh::{BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize};
use solana_program::{
    account_info::{next_account_info, AccountInfo},
    entrypoint,
    entrypoint::ProgramResult,
    pubkey::Pubkey,
    program_error::ProgramError,
    system_instruction,
    program::invoke_signed,
    msg,
    log::sol_log,
};

entrypoint!(process_instruction);

// Assuming `TransferRequest` and `process_transfer_requests` from the previous example.
#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct TransferRequest {
    pub recipient: Pubkey,
    pub amount: u64,
}

#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug)]
pub struct TransferRequests {
    pub requests: Vec<TransferRequest>,
}

// Function to create a PDA for the fund account
pub fn create_fund_pda(program_id: &Pubkey) -> (Pubkey, u8) {
    // Replace "fundaccountseed" with your chosen seed
    Pubkey::find_program_address(&[b"fundAccount"], program_id)
}

// Example function to process payouts, using the PDA for transfers
fn process_payouts(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    transfer_requests: Vec<TransferRequest>,
) -> ProgramResult {
    let accounts_iter = &mut accounts.iter();

    // Assuming the first account is the PDA for the fund and the second is the system program.
    let fund_pda_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;
    let system_program_account = next_account_info(accounts_iter)?;

    let (fund_pda, bump_seed) = create_fund_pda(program_id);
    assert_eq!(&fund_pda, fund_pda_account.key);

    for request in transfer_requests {
        // Logging is optional and used here for demonstration.
        msg!(
            "Processing transfer request for recipient: {}, amount: {}",
            request.recipient,
            request.amount
        );
        
        let transfer_instruction = system_instruction::transfer(
            &fund_pda_account.key,
            &request.recipient,
            request.amount,
        );

        sol_log(&format!("Transfer instruction: {:?}", transfer_instruction));

        // Since PDAs cannot sign for themselves, you use `invoke_signed` with the appropriate seeds.
        invoke_signed(
            &transfer_instruction,
            &[fund_pda_account.clone(), system_program_account.clone()],
            &[&[&b"fundAccount"[..], &[bump_seed]]],
        )?;
    }

    Ok(())
}

/// The main entry point for the Solana program.
fn process_instruction(
    program_id: &Pubkey,
    accounts: &[AccountInfo],
    instruction_data: &[u8],
) -> ProgramResult {
    sol_log("Received instruction data");

    // Log the received instruction data length
    sol_log(&format!(
        "Instruction data length: {}",
        instruction_data.len()
    ));

    match TransferRequests::try_from_slice(instruction_data) {
        Ok(transfer_requests) => {
            sol_log("Deserialized TransferRequests successfully");
            sol_log(&format!("Number of requests: {}", transfer_requests.requests.len()));
            // Continue processing as normal...
            process_payouts(program_id, accounts, transfer_requests.requests)
        }
        Err(e) => {
            sol_log("Failed to deserialize TransferRequests");
            sol_log(&format!("Deserialization error: {:?}", e));
            Err(ProgramError::InvalidInstructionData)
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my javascript program that interfaces with that:

```
const solanaWeb3 = require('@solana/web3.js');
const { Keypair, Transaction, TransactionInstruction, PublicKey, SystemProgram } = solanaWeb3;
const borsh = require('borsh');
const fs = require('fs');

const keypairPath = process.argv[2];
if (!keypairPath) {
    console.error('Usage: node <script.js> <keypairPath>');
    process.exit(1);
}

const keypairData = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(keypairPath, 'utf8'));

async function airdropToPDA(connection, fundPDA) {
    const LAMPORTS_PER_SOL = solanaWeb3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL;
    let airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
        fundPDA,
        1 * LAMPORTS_PER_SOL
    );
    await connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature);
    console.log(`Airdropped 1 SOL to ${fundPDA.toString()}`);
}


class TransferRequest {
    constructor({recipient, amount}) {
        // Ensure the recipient public key is stored as a raw 32-byte array
        this.recipient = new PublicKey(recipient).toBuffer();
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}

class TransferRequests {
    constructor({requests}) {
        this.requests = requests;
    }
}

const schema = new Map([
    [TransferRequest, {kind: 'struct', fields: [['recipient', [32]], ['amount', 'u64']]}],
    [TransferRequests, {kind: 'struct', fields: [['requests', [TransferRequest]]]}]
]);

async function sendBulkTransfer(connection, programId, seeds, transferRequests, payer) {
    // Derive the PDA
    const [fundPDA, bumpSeed] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(seeds, programId);

    console.log("fundPDA: ", fundPDA.toBase58());

    // Prepare transfer requests
    const transfers = transferRequests.map(request => new TransferRequest({recipient: request.recipient, amount: request.amount}));
    const bulkTransferData = new TransferRequests({requests: transfers});

    const serializedData = borsh.serialize(schema, bulkTransferData);

    const keys = [
        { pubkey: fundPDA, isSigner: false, isWritable: true },
        { pubkey: SystemProgram.programId, isSigner: false, isWritable: false }
    ];

    const instruction = new TransactionInstruction({
        keys,
        programId,
        data: serializedData,
    });

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(instruction);
    const signedTransaction = await solanaWeb3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [payer]);
    console.log("Signed transaction: ", signedTransaction);
}

async function main() {
    const connection = new solanaWeb3.Connection(solanaWeb3.clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');
    const programId = new solanaWeb3.PublicKey("HFaVb5gk49QzxuNNjSbJKGZ7rC1qR8LqYDNaX539Gntx");
    const seeds = [Buffer.from("fundAccount", 'utf8')];
    const payer = solanaWeb3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(keypairData));

    // Derive the PDA
    const [fundPDA, _bumpSeed] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(seeds, programId);
    // Airdrop to PDA
    await airdropToPDA(connection, fundPDA);

    // in a loop, create a new keypair, extract the public key, and add it to the transferRequests array
    const transferRequests = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const keypair = Keypair.generate();
        const publicKey = keypair.publicKey;
        transferRequests.push(new TransferRequest({recipient: publicKey, amount: 0.001 * solanaWeb3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL}));
    }

    //console.log("transfer requests: ", transferRequests);

    sendBulkTransfer(connection, programId, seeds, transferRequests, payer)
        .then(() => console.log("Bulk transfer submitted."))
        .catch((e) => console.error(e));
}

main().then(() => console.log("Completed")).catch(console.error);
```

Currently, the instructions are correctly being read by the Solana program, but it is encountering an error when trying to `invoke_signed`:

```
'Program 9h64X77j5Anpe3gyBeMx1WpkLVBnyG7nP3YHPcNyLAfK invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Received instruction data',
    'Program log: Instruction data length: 404',
    'Program log: Deserialized TransferRequests successfully',
    'Program log: Number of requests: 10',
    'Program log: Processing transfer request for recipient: 39QQCWN5n4K45B5NFL2RcuUbGrpk4a2ud7QgKaK2e5WU, amount: 1000000',
    'Program log: Transfer instruction: Instruction { program_id: 11111111111111111111111111111111, accounts: [AccountMeta { pubkey: GgfViAgvtuWuW8mHXJwYkaMWHT8t1jVvDoV3jATmfY2A, is_signer: true, is_writable: true }, AccountMeta { pubkey: 39QQCWN5n4K45B5NFL2RcuUbGrpk4a2ud7QgKaK2e5WU, is_signer: false, is_writable: true }], data: [2, 0, 0, 0, 64, 66, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] }',
    'Program 9h64X77j5Anpe3gyBeMx1WpkLVBnyG7nP3YHPcNyLAfK consumed 53253 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program 9h64X77j5Anpe3gyBeMx1WpkLVBnyG7nP3YHPcNyLAfK failed: Instruction passed to inner instruction is too large (12884933690 > 1280)'
```

i.e. it's saying the instruction is too large. I've tried to google this problem and mostly people say to use an earlier version of the Solana CLI but when I do that I run into all kinds of dependency problems. Any help with this would be so appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to upgrade all of your tools to the same consistent values, preferably 1.18 at the time of this writing, Solana crates and CLI.

You can upgrade the CLI with:

```
solana-install init 1.18.7
```

And in your Cargo.toml:

```
solana-program = "1.18"
```

More information about this particular issue at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/issues/31960#issuecomment-1668682153